# PHP Package Dompdf renders empty pdf files

Tags: php, pdf

I'm using the package dompdf/dompdf v2.0.1 ([link here](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)). I've followed the basic example given on their page, creating the following Php file:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('<p>Hello World!</p>');
$dompdf->setPape('A4');
$dompdf->stream();
```

As expected, the library creates a PDF file and sends a response to the browser to download it. The problem is, the PDF I get in return is completely empty. I've even looked at the raw code for the file and there's no mention of the text I've added.

I'm running php-fpm v8.1.13 on Alpine inside a Docker container. I've installed the necessary Php extensions (ext-dom, ext-mbstring) as well as GD. The official page says that the library works under PHP 8.1, and there's even a [debug page](https://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php) that shows it's working under php 8.1.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I just tried it under PHP 7.4 and I got the same results, so I doubt it's a problem with my PHP version. I also tried running it on php 8.1 on a WAMP server and the same thing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I just got an answer from someone on the GitHub page for the library. You have to call `$domPdf->render()` to actually build the file. I mistakenly thought that was for a different purpose and you had to call `$domPdf->stream()` only.